# How can I set up VSCode and Python which is in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, miniconda

I like to use VSCode as an IDE.

I'm starting to develop python application. I want to know if there is a way I can set up Miniconda environment in Docker and connect it to VSCode for compilation and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. The issue tracking this sort of thing is https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/79 .